# CsvHelper ConvertUsing not changing output

Tags: c#, csv, export-to-csv, csvhelper

I'm trying to use the `ConvertUsing` method of the [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) library (v 2.4.0).

I've read the documentation about [ConvertUsing](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#mapping-convert-using) but can't get it to work.

I'm using a simple class:

```
public class Test
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

With this `ClassMap`:

```
public class TestClassMap : CsvClassMap<Test>
{
    public override void CreateMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id).Name("id").ConvertUsing(row => 11111);
        Map(m => m.Title).Name("title").ConvertUsing(row => row.GetField("title") + " 123");
    }
}
```

My code which uses these creates an instance of the class and then writes it to CSV:

```
var test = new Test() { Id = 99, Title = "Test title" };

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter("test.csv"))
{
    var csv = new CsvWriter(streamWriter);
    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TestClassMap>();
    csv.WriteRecord(test);
}
```

However the output file `test.csv` is always the following format:

```
id,title
99,Test title
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
id,title
11111,Test title 123
```

And the `ConvertUsing` is being ignored. I've tried only converting the `Id`, and only the `Title`, but this doesn't work either.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 12):

Currently `ConvertUsing` is only used when reading.

You can use a custom type converter if you want to customize the output. You also have some limited abilities through the type converter options.

Comment: So what would someone do to modify output before writing a file?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I added more to the answer.

Comment: There is a simple(r) example over here on writing to csv with a custom type-converter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31817621/430885

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar need and this is what I made in order to modify the content before saving it into a csv file.

I have a custom class called StringNormalizer that implements CsvHelper.TypeConversion.ITypeConverter interface.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using CsvHelper.TypeConversion;

namespace MyNamespaceInHere {    
    public class StringNormalizer : ITypeConverter {
        public bool CanConvertFrom(Type type) {
            if (type == typeof(string)) return true;
            return false;
        }
        public bool CanConvertTo(Type type) {
            if (type == typeof(string)) return true;
            return false;
        }
        public object ConvertFromString(TypeConverterOptions options, string text) { return normalize(text); }
        public string ConvertToString(TypeConverterOptions options, object value) {
            if (value == null) return string.Empty;
            if (value.GetType() == typeof(string)) {
                string str = (string)value;
                return normalize(str);
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
        public string normalize(string field) {
            // Do stuff in here and return normalized string
            return field + " just a sample";
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my main program where I have defined mappings I use it like this

```
public sealed class ConMap : CsvClassMap<Contact> {        
        public override void CreateMap() {
            Map(m => m.FirstName).Name("FirstName").TypeConverter<StringNormalizer>();
        }
    }
```

And thus all that is saved to csv are "run through" my string normalizer.