# Forcing ISO 8601 with CSVHelper

Tags: c#, datetime, iso8601, datetimeoffset, csvhelper

I'm trying to get a ISO8601 formatted date in the following format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff zzz` to a `.csv` using `CsvHelper`.

```
public System.DateTimeOffset ChangeDT { get; set; }
Map(m => m.ChangeDT).ConvertUsing<string>(row => row.GetField<DateTimeOffset>("ChangeDT").ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff zzz"));
```

Although the above code produces:

```
6/10/2014 12:00:00 AM -05:00
```

what I'm looking for it to output is:

```
2014-06-10 12:00:00.1234567 -05:00
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Might http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678385/csvhelper-convertusing-not-changing-output be relevant? (Admittedly it's very old...)

Comment: Possibly, but I'm using it for other fields as well, such as converting a string.ToUpper, and that works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply provide [the `"o"` format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip) to the type converter.

```
Map(m => m.ChangeDT).TypeConverterOption("o");
```