# Custom conversions when writing CSV files using CsvHelper

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I've been doing some CSV reading and writing lately, and ran across [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) which is fantastic so far.  I've ran into one small problem; I use a custom converter when reading the files, but when I write them back out, that format is lost.  My CSV format looks like this:

```
67,1234-1,20150115,750,20150115,1340,549,549,406,0,FRG
```

The fields `20150115,750` map to a single `DateTime` field called `Start` (So, 01/15/2015 7:50 AM).  My class map looks like this:

```
public sealed class DutyMap : CsvClassMap<Duty>
{
    static readonly CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    public DutyMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.PersonId).Index(0);
        Map(m => m.DutyName).Index(1);
        Map(m => m.Start).ConvertUsing(row => ParseDate(row.GetField<String>(2), row.GetField<String>(3)));
        Map(m => m.End).ConvertUsing(row => ParseDate(row.GetField<String>(4), row.GetField<String>(5)));
        Map(m => m.DutyTime1).Index(6);
        Map(m => m.DutyTime2).Index(7);
        Map(m => m.FlightTime).Index(8);
        Map(m => m.CreditHours).Index(9);
        Map(m => m.DutyType).Index(10);
    }

    private static DateTime ParseDate(string date, string time)
    {
        DateTime ret;

        if (time.Length < 4)
            time = new String('0', 4 - time.Length) + time;

        if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(date + time, "yyyyMMddHHmm", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out ret))
            throw new FormatException(String.Format("Could not parse DateTime.  Date: {0} Time: {1}", date, time));

        return ret;
    }
}
```

This works great, and I can now call parse an entire file like so:

```
var csv = new CsvReader(sr);
csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<DutyMap>();

Data = csv.GetRecords<Duty>().ToList();
```

However, when I *write* the file:

```
csv.WriteRecords(Data);
```

The file is written out like so:

```
67,7454-1,1/15/2015 7:50:00 AM,1/15/2015 1:40:00 PM,549,549,406,0,FPG
```

Looking through the documentation, I don't see a way to specify a conversation function upon *writing*, only *reading*.  The only solution I've found so far is to manually write each record by hand:

```
var csv = new CsvWriter(sw);
foreach (var item in Data)
{
    csv.WriteField(item.PersonId);
    csv.WriteField(item.DutyName);
    csv.WriteField(item.Start.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
    csv.WriteField(item.Start.ToString("Hmm"));
    csv.WriteField(item.End.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
    csv.WriteField(item.End.ToString("Hmm"));
    csv.WriteField(item.DutyTime1);
    csv.WriteField(item.DutyTime2);
    csv.WriteField(item.FlightTime);
    csv.WriteField(item.CreditHours);
    csv.WriteField(item.DutyType);

    csv.NextRecord();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it with a custom type converters (https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/wiki/Custom-TypeConverter). Just override `ConvertToString` method.

```
public class TestConverter : DefaultTypeConverter
{
    public override string ConvertToString(TypeConverterOptions options, object value)
    {
        return base.ConvertToString(options, value);
    }
}
```

and specify converter when mapping:

```
Map(m => m.PersonId).Index(0).TypeConverter<TestConverter>();
```

Comment: Thanks!  I started looking at that, but the documentation looked a bit sparse.  I'll dig into it more!

Comment: Oh, also would this let me split one field (`Start`) into two different fields in the CSV file?  Remember, I have to split up the date portion and time portion.

Comment: Just use Map statements multiple times with different columns names Map(m => m.PersonId).Index(0).Name("col1"); Map(m => m.PersonId).Index(0).Name("col2");

Comment: I had to use this code:
public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)

Answer (score 0):

If you end up here looking for a way to convert doubles in round-trip compatible format, you can use the below which uses the [G17 format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#RFormatString).

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:/path..."))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<double?>(new TypeConverterOptions 
    { 
        Formats = new string[] { "G17" } 
    });

    csv.WriteRecords(collection);
}
```