# CsvHelper parse csv and convert string to DateTime

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I am working with CsvHelper and being able to parse csv file. My question is how can I parse the `Date` into `DateTime` object

I want to convert it via CsvHelper while it is parsing the csv rather than iterating the collection

```
public static List<StockModel> SplitCsv(string csv)
{
    var textReader = new StringReader(csv);

    var csvr = new CsvReader(textReader);
    csvr.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<ModelMap>();

    var records = csvr.GetRecords<StockModel>().ToList();
    return records;
}

public class StockModel
{
    public string Date { get; set; } // I want this object to be DateTime
    public string Base { get; set; }
    public string Open { get; set; }
}

public sealed class ModelMap : CsvClassMap<StockModel>
{
    public ModelMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Date);
        Map(m => m.Base);
        Map(m => m.Open);
    }
}
```

CSV example

```
Date,Base,Open
2016-02-29,1437.530029,1445.839966
2016-02-25,1431.439941,1431.439941
2016-02-24,1430.459961,1432.430054
```

Comment: What did you try? what are base and open supposed to be?

Comment: @Valentin, I want to convert it via CsvHelper

Comment: Does it make sense http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817473/custom-conversions-when-writing-csv-files-using-csvhelper ?

Comment: You might explain how it is not working - it converts from any format legal for the current culture

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding of `CsvHelper`, The default built in converters will handle most cases of type conversion where it should be able to convert the type of the properties of your class. No need to make them all strings. Just put them in the type you want. Once the property name matches the column name (if present) in the csv then it auto maps those fields to their matching property

```
public class StockModel
{
    //2016-02-29
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } // CsvHelper should be able to infer type
    //1437.530029
    public decimal Base { get; set; }
    //1445.839966
    public decimal Open { get; set; }
}


public static List<StockModel> SplitCsv(string csv)
{
    var textReader = new StringReader(csv);

    var csvr = new CsvReader(textReader);

    var records = csvr.GetRecords<StockModel>().ToList();

    return records;
}
```

From [Wiki](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/wiki/Basics) on github

Using CsvHelper is really easy. It's default settings are setup for the most common scenarios.

Here is a little setup data.

**Actors.csv:**

```
Id,FirstName,LastName  
1,Arnold,Schwarzenegger  
2,Matt,Damon  
3,Christian,Bale
```

**Actor.cs (custom class object that represents an actor):**

```
public class Actor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Reading**

**Reading the CSV file using CsvReader:**

```
var csv = new CsvReader( new StreamReader( "Actors.csv" ) );
var actorsList = csv.GetRecords<Actor>();
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by registering a `ClassMap`:

```cs
using var reader = new StreamReader(@"");
using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<TransactionLineMap>(); // <-- this line
var records = csv.GetRecords<TransactionLine>();
```

In the `ClassMap`, you can define the format of the DateTime using `TypeConverterOption.Format("your-date-format")`

```cs
internal class TransactionLineMap : ClassMap<TransactionLine>
{
    public TransactionLineMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Timestamp)
            .TypeConverter<CsvHelper.TypeConversion.DateTimeConverter>()
            .TypeConverterOption.Format("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it support a custom converter? Like converting epoch time to DateTime?

Answer (score -1):

May be this will help you:

```
        string dateTime = "2016-02-29";
        DateTime dt;
        DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTime,
            "yyyy-MM-dd",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal,
            out dt);
```

put proper code from this example into your set operator.