# CsvHelper changing how dates and times are output

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I am using [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to write some CSV files and want to change the format of my dates and times to something specific. Following the advice from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31817621/223742 I can successfully create maps for each of my classes.

However it has the distinct disadvantage that I now need to create custom maps for all the classes that I want to export. As I always want all the fields exported this becomes a maintenance nightmare as I have to amend maps each time.

So is there any simple way to tell CsvHelper to write **all dates and times** using a specific format?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set it globally per type using `TypeConverterOptionsFactory`.

```
void Main()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
    {
        var options = new TypeConverterOptions
        {
            Format = "o"
        };
        TypeConverterOptionsFactory.AddOptions<DateTime>(options);

        csv.WriteField(DateTime.Now);
        csv.NextRecord();
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        reader.ReadToEnd().Dump();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2016-09-19T11:01:41.5507054-05:00
```

Comment: the TypeConverterOptionsFactory is not visible any more in version 26.0.1

Answer (score 75):

With newer version (12.1.2) of CsvHelper, it can be achieved by using `TypeConverterOptionsCache`

```
var options = new TypeConverterOptions { Formats = new[] { "MM/dd/yyyy" } };
csvWriter.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime>(options);
```

Output date

```
08/24/1991
```

Version 20 moved `TypeConverterOptionsCache` from `Configuration` to `Context`. So the above becomes

```
var options = new TypeConverterOptions { Formats = new[] { "MM/dd/yyyy" } };
csvWriter.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime>(options);
csvWriter.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime?>(options);
```

Comment: and if you've got a mix of `DateTime` and `DateTime?`, don't forget to register both types!

Comment: Getting `error CS1545: Property, indexer, or event 'CsvContext.TypeConverterOptionsCache' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor methods 'CsvContext.get_TypeConverterOptionsCache()' or 'CsvContext.set_TypeConverterOptionsCache(?)' ` on Linux.

Comment: For CsvHelper 26.0.1 this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 41):

For me it was easier to use CsvHelper attributes on class.

`[Format("yyyy-MM-dd")]` did the job for datetime formatting.

```
namespace BarNamespace
{
    using System;
    using CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes;

    public class Foo
    {
        [Name("ColumnName1")]
        [Format("yyyy-MM-dd")]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [Name("ColumnName2")]
        public string Col2{ get; set; }

        [Name("ColumnName3")]
        public long Col3{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a much more readable way to do things.