# setting a date timeformat using CSVHelper

Tags: csvhelper

I've got a csv file and I'm using csvhelper to do the parsing. I've now got a date thats being formatted in

dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss

however, csv reader doesn't read this has a correct date for my locale.

Is there a way to set the CSV date time format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CsvHelper changing how dates and times are output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564585/csvhelper-changing-how-dates-and-times-are-output)