# String '22-05-1998' was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core-mvc, csvhelper

I am using `CsvHelper` library to read the data from a CSV file looks like

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RACBL.png)

My code:

```
public class CsvTransaction
{

    [Name("Account")]
    public string Account { get; set; }
    [Name("Amount")]
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    [Name("Date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [Name("Note")]
    public string Note { get; set; }
}

public void call()
            {
                using (var StreamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\santo\Downloads\industry.csv"))
                {
                    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(StreamReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    {
                        var records = csvReader.GetRecords<CsvTransaction>().ToList();
                        Console.WriteLine(records.Count);
                        foreach(var item in records)
                         {
                            Console.WriteLine(item.Amount.GetType());
                            Console.WriteLine(item.Note.GetType());
                        

                        CsvAddTransaction(item.Account, item.Amount, item.Date, item.Note);
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
```

when I call this `call()`, it is saying **String '22-05-1998' was not recognized as a valid DateTime**. all the other are giving exact datatypes I needed, but there is a problem with `item.Date`

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you get the same thing if that string is input manually?  If so I suspect that there may be a "surprise" character in your CSV file, something like an em-dash

Comment: @jon P there is no surprise character in CSV file, you can see the data in the image that I have attached

Comment: Not familiar with CSVHelper, but some internet pages suggest that you can use `TypeConverterOption` or `FormatAttribute`. [Page I found is in japanese](https://tomisenblog.com/csvhelper-datetime-mapping/), but there are codes and I think you can found similar topics at SO too. Seems like you have to tell it the format is `DD-MM-YYYY`.

Comment: I assume that "InvariantCulture" also specifies date handling - which would be the US MM/dd/yyyy format So try a culture that uses dd-MM-yyyy. Note that it would also affect handling of decimals (`.` versus `,`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CsvHelper changing how dates and times are output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564585/csvhelper-changing-how-dates-and-times-are-output)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define DateTime format, you are getting this error because parsing mechanism might be expecting something like "MM-dd-yyyy" and instead of that, it receives "dd-MM-yyyy".

Here's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) which describes DateTime formatting in detail.
And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69070912/9685497) is url to potential solution to your problem.

Comment: No, custom date and time format specifiers are case sensitive. There is no `YYYY` format specifier, you need to use `yyyy` instead for 4-digit year.

Comment: you are correct, edited my answer in order to fix that.