# How to specify a custom DateOnly format with CsvReader?

Tags: c#, date, csvhelper, csvreader, dateonly

I need to read a CSV file using CsvReader, however I have a custom date format (yyyyMMdd) which by default can't be converted to `DateOnly`. How can I specify this custom date format? Is that may possible using some annotation?

This is the code I currently have, it fails with

> FormatException: String '20230817' was not recognized as a valid DateOnly.

```
class Foo
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
    public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
}

var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"Title,Date");
sb.AppendLine();
sb.Append(@"hello world,20230817");
sb.AppendLine();


using var stringReader = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
using var csvReader = new CsvReader(stringReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

int lineIndex = 0;

while(csvReader.Read())
{
    if(lineIndex == 0)
    {
        csvReader.ReadHeader();
    } else
    {
        var foo = csvReader.GetRecord<Foo>();
    }

    lineIndex++;
}
```

Comment: I doubt it would be different than the classic `DateTime`, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564585

Comment: btw - I hope that `yyymmdd` is a typo, as the small `m` is minutes and not month, and only 3 `y` instead of 4

Comment: seems to work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gqg1iS

Comment: thank you and all the others, perfect answers :-) now I don't know which to select besides you only having commented, would also have been worth an answer :-) And yeah, should have been `yyyyMMdd`

Comment: IMHO no one should have answered and it should be flagged as duplicate, as I said in the beginning there seems to be no reason to believe it wouldn’t work exactly like DateTime

Answer (score 3):

As [Rand Random commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76921781/how-to-specify-a-custom-dateonly-format-with-csvreader#comment135603426_76921781), you have two ways to add the formatting.

You can simply add the `Format` annotation

```cs
class Foo
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
    
    [Format("yyyyMMdd")]
    public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can set all `DateOnly` values to use the format with `TypeConverterOptionsCache`

```cs
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(@"Title,Date");
sb.AppendLine(@"hello world,20230817");

using var stringReader = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
using var csvReader = new CsvReader(stringReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var options = new TypeConverterOptions { Formats = new[] { "yyyyMMdd" } };
csvReader.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateOnly>(options);

if (csvReader.Read())
{
    csvReader.ReadHeader();

    while (csvReader.Read())
    {
        var foo = csvReader.GetRecord<Foo>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example you can try something like this, since you have to specify the exact format you provide

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"Title,Date");
sb.AppendLine();
sb.Append(@"hello world,20230817");
sb.AppendLine();
using var stringReader = new StringReader(sb.ToString());

using var csvReader = new CsvReader(stringReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

int lineIndex = 0;
while (csvReader.Read())
{
    if (lineIndex == 0)
    {
        csvReader.ReadHeader();
    }
    else
    {
        var foo = new Foo() { Title = csvReader.GetField<string>(0), Date = DateOnly.ParseExact(csvReader.GetField<string>(1), "yyyyMMdd") };
    }
    lineIndex++;
}
```